# Can I set Watir to not open a window?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, watir

Until recently, I was using mechanize to get a web page, then do some parsing with nokogiri. But because some content was loaded with Ajax after I have started using Watir instead. My code looks like this:

```
def get_page(url)
  browser = Watir::Browser.start url
  sleep 1
  page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
  browser.close
  return page
end
```

It works fine but since I am getting a lot of pages the `browser.start` will open a tons of windows. I found the close as you see, but is there a way to just not show the browser window at all?

Comment: You basically want to run it "headless"? There is this: http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/

Comment: Also there's the phantomjs driver (headless only works on mac/linux)

Comment: Yes headless was the word. Got it working with the headless driver. But it is damn slow compared to what I was getting with mechanize. Will have a look at PhantomJs later and see if that will speed up things.